# Archival storage tool: fast, queryable, has api, reliable

Tags: nosql, data-integrity

I have large quantities of structured data coming in over the network from disparate sources, and that data is archived in the filesystem, parsed/analyzed, and eventually makes it's way into a database (mysql) to be accessed by a few apps.  The data is not relational-friendly, and has to be significantly massaged.

I would like to replace the 'archive to filesystem' step with some other system, one that has equivalent reliability (read: zero data loss) but has features of a database including query and api interfaces.  It appears to me that one of the NoSQL products would be perfect for this, as they fulfill the query+api conditions and don't force me to shove the data into a structured format.  I really like mongodb, but AFAGTM it (among other nosql products) sacrifices reliability and data integrity for performance.  I was just about to set up a mongodb instance with journaling enabled, but wanted to be extra-special-super-sure before I did so.

I am not looking for a DMS or related system, as the data is more like log-ish than file-ish.  And obviously I have backups etc.

**TL;DR** 
I'm looking for a NoSQL product that can act as an 'archive' in that it will never eat my data.

Thank you.
Sorry for the novel.